# Duplicate WHERE criteria in joined sub-queries

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I wrote a query which joins fourteen tables. When the criteria returns a lot of rows, the query takes a long time. Here's the original query, with a large `IN` criteria:

```
SELECT r.source_uri AS su_on_r, r.title AS t_on_r, r.subtitle AS s_on_r, r.artist_name AS an_on_r, r.asin AS a_on_r, r.country AS c_on_r, r.release_date AS rd_on_r, string_agg(DISTINCT barcode.barcode::TEXT, '|') AS b_on_barcode, string_agg(DISTINCT genre.genre::TEXT, '|') AS g_on_genre, string_agg(DISTINCT typ.type::TEXT, '|') AS t_on_typ, string_agg(tag.voted_tag::TEXT, '|') AS vt_on_tag, IMAGE.uri AS u_on_image, IMAGE.width AS w_on_image, IMAGE.height AS h_on_image, IMAGE.score AS s_on_image, string_agg(DISTINCT imageType.image_type::TEXT, '|') AS it_on_imageType, string_agg(tag.votes::TEXT, '|') AS v_on_tag, string_agg(DISTINCT url.url::TEXT, '|') AS u_on_url, event.label_name AS ln_on_event, event.cat AS c_on_event, m.position AS p_on_m, m.title AS t_on_m, m.format AS f_on_m, t.position AS p_on_t, t.title AS t_on_t, string_agg(DISTINCT t.duration::TEXT, '|') AS d_on_t, string_agg(DISTINCT tArtist.artist::TEXT, '|') AS a_on_tArtist, string_agg(DISTINCT tComposer.composer::TEXT, '|') AS c_on_tComposer, string_agg(DISTINCT tIsrc.isrc::TEXT, '|') AS i_on_tIsrc
FROM release r
LEFT JOIN release_barcode barcode ON r.source_uri = barcode.source_uri
LEFT JOIN release_genre genre ON r.source_uri = genre.source_uri
LEFT JOIN release_type typ ON r.source_uri = typ.source_uri
LEFT JOIN release_voted_tag tag ON r.source_uri = tag.source_uri
LEFT JOIN release_image IMAGE ON r.source_uri = IMAGE.source_uri
LEFT JOIN release_image_type imageType ON IMAGE.id = imageType.image_id
LEFT JOIN release_url url ON r.source_uri = url.source_uri
LEFT JOIN release_event event ON r.source_uri = event.source_uri
LEFT JOIN medium m ON r.source_uri = m.source_uri
LEFT JOIN track t ON m.id = t.medium
LEFT JOIN track_artist tArtist ON t.id = tArtist.track
LEFT JOIN track_composer tComposer ON t.id = tComposer.track
LEFT JOIN track_isrc tIsrc ON t.id = tIsrc.track
WHERE r.source_uri IN (
  'https://api.discogs.com/releases/1955915'
  ,'https://api.discogs.com/releases/8602631'
  ,[and so on for about thirty more URIs]
  )
GROUP BY su_on_r, t_on_r, s_on_r, an_on_r, a_on_r, c_on_r, rd_on_r, u_on_image, w_on_image, h_on_image, s_on_image, ln_on_event, c_on_event, p_on_m, t_on_m, f_on_m, p_on_t, t_on_t;
```

Looking at explain, much of the effort is in sorting because of the large GROUP BY statement: https://explain.depesz.com/s/dV5o

**You can see that the aggregation works on >90k rows.** The row count is so large because of the number of joins, with many 1:m tables resulting in an exponential growth of rows.

### First attempt, move aggregations to joined sub-queries

So I wondered how I could rewrite the query to not have to combine all those rows. I decided to write the joins as sub-queries instead, and move the aggregations into those sub-queries.

My first attempt was (just one example for `release_barcode`, repeated for all tables):

```
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT source_uri, string_agg(DISTINCT barcode::TEXT, '|') AS b_on_barcode
    FROM release_barcode
    GROUP BY source_uri
) AS barcode ON r.source_uri = barcode.source_uri
```

This worked in that fewer rows were returned, and I didn't need to do the enormous sort because there was no GROUP BY in the top level query.

However, this was slower! **This was because the query planner didn't appear to apply the criteria for the top level query first.** Instead, it joined the entire tables together.

### Next attempt, duplicate criteria in sub queries

So I tried something different; to force the filter in each sub-query, I simply duplicated the criteria:

```
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT source_uri, string_agg(DISTINCT barcode::TEXT, '|') AS b_on_barcode
    FROM release_barcode
    WHERE source_uri IN (
      'https://api.discogs.com/releases/1955915'
      ,'https://api.discogs.com/releases/8602631'
      ,[and so on for about thirty more URIs]
      )
    GROUP BY source_uri
) AS barcode ON r.source_uri = barcode.source_uri
```

That `WHERE` clause was simply duplicated in each sub-query.

The result speaks for itself: https://explain.depesz.com/s/exSw

**A much more complicated query, but 100x faster!**

But of course the duplication of criteria smells extremely pongy.

So my question is twofold:

- Does this type of optimisation have a name, and is it frowned upon?
- Is there a better way of doing this, to avoid the duplication (see my first attempt)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve comes to mind.

Comment: Try to disable nested loops by setting `set enable_nestloop to off` and rerun first query.

Comment: 14 tables is too much for the planner, and it will enter geqo-mode (see `geqo_threshold` and `join_collapse_limit` ) Try isolating a tight cluster of the referred tables and put this cluster in a CTE, and refer to this CTE in the main query. (this wil  reduce your query to 7+8 range table entries)

Comment: @JustMe that seems to have made it worse... I ran the query about 30s ago, it's still going...

Comment: @jarih Feel free to suggest dimensions to make this more minimal, given the issue is the number of joins and the duplication of large criteria.

Comment: And a possible first step would be to squeeze the `WHERE r.source_uri IN ( ... list of 30 ...)` into a CTE. BTW: `r.source_uri = barcode.source_uri` looks like a terrible choice for a PK/FK column.

Answer (score 0):

- increase `geqo_treshold` (or even `join_collapse_limit`) **Note:** this may increase planning time to more than a second
- Reduce the number of rangetable entries by splitting off *tightly* related tables into CTE's:
- [the row sizes are rathe large] avoid *fat* indexes and fat tables, (such as the `%uri` field: put it into a separate table and refer to it via a surrogate key)
- [next step would probably be: put the whole query (without the aggregation) in a third CTE, and do the aggregation in the main query]

---

```
WITH rel AS (
        SELECT * FROM release 
        WHERE source_uri IN (
  'https://api.discogs.com/releases/1955915'
  ,'https://api.discogs.com/releases/8602631'
  -- ,[and so on for about thirty more URIs]
        )
, media AS (
        SELECT *
        FROM medium m -- ON r.source_uri = m.source_uri
        LEFT JOIN track t ON m.id = t.medium
        LEFT JOIN track_artist tArtist ON t.id = tArtist.track
        LEFT JOIN track_composer tComposer ON t.id = tComposer.track
        LEFT JOIN track_isrc tIsrc ON t.id = tIsrc.track
        )
SELECT r.source_uri AS su_on_r, r.title AS t_on_r, r.subtitle AS s_on_r, r.artist_name AS an_on_r
        , r.asin AS a_on_r, r.country AS c_on_r, r.release_date AS rd_on_r
        , string_agg(DISTINCT barcode.barcode::TEXT, '|') AS b_on_barcode
        , string_agg(DISTINCT genre.genre::TEXT, '|') AS g_on_genre
        , string_agg(DISTINCT typ.type::TEXT, '|') AS t_on_typ
        , string_agg(tag.voted_tag::TEXT, '|') AS vt_on_tag
        , img.uri AS u_on_image, img.width AS w_on_image
        , img.height AS h_on_image, img.score AS s_on_image
        , string_agg(DISTINCT imageType.image_type::TEXT, '|') AS it_on_imageType
        , string_agg(tag.votes::TEXT, '|') AS v_on_tag
        , string_agg(DISTINCT url.url::TEXT, '|') AS u_on_url
        , event.label_name AS ln_on_event, event.cat AS c_on_event
        , m.position AS p_on_m, m.title AS t_on_m, m.format AS f_on_m
        , m.position AS p_on_t, m.title AS t_on_t <<-- !!need to fix thes in the CTE
        , string_agg(DISTINCT m.duration::TEXT, '|') AS d_on_t
        , string_agg(DISTINCT m.artist::TEXT, '|') AS a_on_tArtist
        , string_agg(DISTINCT m.composer::TEXT, '|') AS c_on_tComposer
        , string_agg(DISTINCT m.isrc::TEXT, '|') AS i_on_tIsrc
FROM rel r -- <<--- ##########################  CTE
LEFT JOIN release_barcode barcode       ON      r.source_uri = barcode.source_uri
LEFT JOIN release_genre genre           ON      r.source_uri = genre.source_uri
LEFT JOIN release_type typ              ON      r.source_uri = typ.source_uri
LEFT JOIN release_voted_tag tag         ON      r.source_uri = tag.source_uri
LEFT JOIN release_image img             ON      r.source_uri = img.source_uri
  LEFT JOIN release_image_type imageType         ON img.id = imageType.image_id
LEFT JOIN release_url url               ON      r.source_uri = url.source_uri
LEFT JOIN release_event event           ON      r.source_uri = event.source_uri
LEFT JOIN media                         ON      r.source_uri = media.source_uri -- <<--- ##########################  CTE
GROUP BY su_on_r, t_on_r, s_on_r, an_on_r
        , a_on_r, c_on_r, rd_on_r
        , u_on_image, w_on_image, h_on_image
        , s_on_image, ln_on_event, c_on_event
        , p_on_m, t_on_m, f_on_m, p_on_t, t_on_t
        ;
```

---

Note: I made a few errors when moving terms to the `media` CTE. There is still some renaming to be done...